# Transforming $e^{m i\beta+n i \gamma}$ into $x^m y^n$

Tags: replacement, complex

I want to write code to transform $e^{m i\beta+n i \gamma}$ into $x^m y^n$, where $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

For example, I write the follow code when $m=3,n=2$:

```
In[1]:= Coefficient[3 I be+ 2 I ga,be]/I
Out[1]= 3

In[2]:= Exp[3 I be+ 2 I ga]/.{Exp[a_]-> x^(Coefficient[a, be]/I)y^(Coefficient[a, ga]/I)}
Out[2]= 1
```

I cannot transform $e^{3i \beta +2 i \gamma}$ into $x^3 y^2$.
I also want $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. For example, $m=-3$, $n=4$.

Comment: If `Exp[3 I β + 2 I γ] /. {β -> -I Log[x], γ -> -I Log[y]} // Simplify` doesn't suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need.